# Get item from db and let Spring MVC binder populate it

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data

I have

- JPA entity

  ```
  @Entity
  public class Tag {
      @Id
      private Long id;
      private String name;
      // getters, setters ...
  }
  ```
- a form to edit a tag `http://localhost:8080/tag/{id}`

  ```
  <form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name" />
  </form>
  ```
- a controller method

  ```
  @RequestMapping("{id}")
  public String save(@ModelAttribute("tag") Tag tag) {
      tagRepository.save(tag);
  }
  ```

What will be the best way to actually get the tag from the database and then let Spring populate its properties from the request parameters?

- create a `WebArgumentResolver` and annotate the method parameter with @PathVariable("id") (or @RequestParam("id") if I pass the id as a request parameter)
- modify the binder in a method annotated with `@InitBinder` (and how?)
- create another method annotated with @ModelAttribute("tag") where to populate the item first from the db
- anything else?

This is not specifically limited to JPA and Spring Data, but that was my case and I thought it's more clear.